# How to select duplicate values from a list in java?

Tags: java, list, duplicates, unique

For example my list contains {4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8} and I want final result = {6, 6, 7, 7}

One way is to loop through the list and eliminate unique values (4, 8 in this case).

Is there any other efficient way rather than looping through list ? I asked this question because the list that I am working is very large ?
My code is

```
List<Long> duplicate = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
     Long item = (Long) list.get(i);
     if (!duplicate.contains(item)) {
          duplicate.add(item);
         }
     }
```

Comment: You will have to loop through the entire list, at least once if you want to find all duplicates. There is no 'more efficient' way to do this with a list, if you have to compare every value in the list, to make it more efficient the solution lies in the creation of the list.

Comment: You need at least one loop. If you want a more efficient code (not guaranteed in all cases though) you could try by ordering the list first and then checking if "neighbors" are different (if so, you have a unique item, just remove it from the list)

Comment: You could always print out the list and tally up the duplicates if you'd rather not loop.

Comment: You are aware that your code does not do what you're asking for in your question?

Answer (score 9):

Some good answers so far but another option just for the fun of it. Loop through the list trying to place each number into a Set e.g. a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). If the add method returns false you know the number is a duplicate and should go into the duplicate list.

EDIT: Something like this should do it

```
Set<Number> unique = new HashSet<>();
List<Number> duplicates = new ArrayList<>();
for( Number n : inputList ) {
    if( !unique.add( n ) ) {
        duplicates.add( n );
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the input data is "large" you should pre-allocate the sizes of the collections.

Comment: It only adds the second (and third etc.) occurences to the duplicates list, not the first occurence as it's not available in the set yet.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any other efficient way rather than looping through list ?

You could hire a magic elf and let it do it for you. How would you ever want to do this without looping through it? If you don't loop through the list, you even won't be able to have a look at the elements. It is like you want to sum a whole bunch of numbers together without looking at those numbers. Summing elements is much easier than searching for duplicates or searching for unique elements. In general, 97% of what code does is looping through lists and data and process and update it.

So, said that, you **have to** loop. Now you might want to choose the most efficient way. Some methods come to mind:

- Sort all the numbers and then loop only once through it to find duplicates (since they will be next to each other). However, keep in mind that sorting algorithms also loop through the data.
- For each element in the list, check if there is another element with the same value. (This is how you did it. This means you have two loops inside each other. (`contains` loops through the list of course.))

Answer (score 4):

```
List<Number> inputList = Arrays.asList(4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8);
List<Number> result = new ArrayList<Number>();
for(Number num : inputList) {
   if(Collections.frequency(inputList, num) > 1) {
       result.add(num);
   }
}
```

I am not sure about the efficiency, but I find the code easy to read (and that should be preferred.

EDIT: changing `Lists.newArrayList()` to `new ArrayList<Number>();`

Comment: I guess you're using some 3rd party library here... (`Lists.newArrayList()`)? But you could just use `new ArrayList<>()`;

Comment: @Junaid I know. I was referring to `Lists.newArrayList()`

Comment: This is actually a good task for using Guava and those filters and predicates.

Comment: I realised after I commented. Excuse me. ;)

Comment: Sure, readability is very important, but it has quadratic complexity and that too bad. As a Guava user, you could enjoy `Multiset` [like I did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45871404/581205). Without Guava, it's maybe one more line for a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 4):

I like answer [Java 8, Streams to find the duplicate elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677256/java-8-streams-to-find-the-duplicate-elements). Solution return only unique duplicates.

```
 Integer[] numbers = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4 };
 Set<Integer> allItems = new HashSet<>();
 Set<Integer> duplicates = Arrays.stream(numbers)
    .filter(n -> !allItems.add(n)) //Set.add() returns false if the item was already in the set.
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
 System.out.println(duplicates); // [1, 4]
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, he wants ALL the repeated numbers. In your example woul be: [1,1,4,4]

Answer (score 1):

Have a

```
Map<Integer, Integer> numberToOccurance = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

maintain count and number, at the end iterate keyset and get values with more than one count

Comment: Or TreeMap if you want the numbers to be sorted.

Comment: why do we want overhead of sorting, Hash is faster!

Comment: well, just if the OP wants the numbers to be sorted. In the sample the numbers are sorted.

Comment: @Jigar, well If i use Tree or Hash Map, I still have to iterate. The actual data that I am dealing with is a list of large encrypted text items.

Comment: @puce: If for some reason the result should be sorted (although noone has mentioned that), it would be faster to sort the result list instead of using a TreeMap for counting the number of occurances just to have the potential benefit later, that the result is already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Your `List` should ideally have been a `Set` which doesn't allow duplicates in the first place. As an alternative to looping, you could either convert and switch to `Set` or use it intermediately to eliminate duplicates as follows:

```
List<Long> dupesList = Arrays.asList(4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L);

Set<Long> noDupesSet = new HashSet<Long>(dupesList);
System.out.println(noDupesSet); // prints: [4, 6, 7, 8]

// To convert back to List
Long[] noDupesArr = noDupesSet.toArray(new Long[noDupesSet.size()]);
List<Long> noDupesList = Arrays.asList(noDupesArr);
System.out.println(noDupesList); // prints: [4, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, he wants ALL the repeated numbers. In your example woul be: [6,6,7,7]

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class FindDuplicate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Load all your ArrayList
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Jhon");
        list.add("Jency");
        list.add("Mike");
        list.add("Dmitri");
        list.add("Mike");

        // Set will not allow duplicates
        Set<String> checkDuplicates = new HashSet<String>();

        System.out.println("Actual list " + list);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            String items = list.get(i);
            if (!checkDuplicates.add(items)) {
                // retain the item from set interface
                System.out.println("Duplicate in that list " + items);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Guava and Java 8, it's trivial and fast:

```
Multiset<Integer> multiset = HashMultiset.create(list);
return list.stream()
    .filter(i -> multiset.count(i) > 1)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The first line computes the counts using a sort of a hash map. The remainder is more than obvious.

Something like this could simulate the multiset:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> multiset = new HashMap<>();
list.stream().forEach(i -> 
    multiset.compute(i, (ignored, old) -> old==null ? 1 : old+1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

*again lambda saves the day:*

```
List<Long> duplicates = duplicate.stream()
  .collect( Collectors.collectingAndThen( Collectors.groupingBy( Function.identity() ),
    map -> {
      map.values().removeIf( v -> v.size() < 2 );  // eliminate unique values (4, 8 in this case)
      return( map.values().stream().flatMap( List::stream ).collect( Collectors.toList() ) );
    } ) );  // [6, 6, 7, 7]
```

*the speed-optimized version of the above solution:*

```
List<Long> duplicates = duplicate.stream().collect( Collectors.collectingAndThen(
    Collectors.groupingBy( Function.identity(), Collectors.counting() ),
    map -> {
      map.values().removeIf( v -> v < 2 );  // eliminate unique values (4, 8 in this case)
      return( map.entrySet().stream().collect( Collector.of( ArrayList<Long>::new, (list, e) -> {
        for( long n = 0; n < e.getValue(); n++ )
          list.add( e.getKey() );
      }, (l1, l2) -> null ) ) );
    } ) );  // [6, 6, 7, 7]
```

the long values of `duplicate` are not saved but counted — quite certainly the fastest and most space-saving variant

Answer (score 0):

The following will work with [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections):

```
IntBag bag = IntLists.mutable.with(4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8).toBag().selectDuplicates();
```

If you want boxed values instead of primitives, the following will work:

```
Bag<Integer> bag = Lists.mutable.with(4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8).toBag().selectDuplicates();
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41262509/11256849

```
for (String s : yourList){
     if (indexOfNth(yourList, s, 2) != -1){
         Log.d(TAG, s);
      }
   }
```

Using this method:

```
public static <T> int indexOfNth(ArrayList list, T find, int nthOccurrence) {
        if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) return -1;
        int hitCount = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
            if (list.get(index).equals(find)) {
                hitCount++;
            }
            if (hitCount == nthOccurrence) return index;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Given that you can do this by looping through the list only once, I wouldn't worry about performance too much.  If you search for more performant solutions then you'll probably end up over-complicating the code and the readability and maintainability will suffer.  At the end of the day, if you want to check the whole list for duplicates then you have to visit every element.

I'd advise writing the obvious solution and see how it performs.  You'll probably be surprised how fast Java can iterate over a list, even if it is particularly large.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my version of the solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> randomNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> expandingPlace = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> sequenceOfDuplicates = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        randomNumbers.add((int) (Math.random() * 10));
        expandingPlace.add(randomNumbers.get(i));
    }

    System.out.println(randomNumbers); // Original list.

    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.size(); i++) {
        if (expandingPlace.get(i) == expandingPlace.get(i + 1)) {
            expandingPlace.add(0);
            sequenceOfDuplicates.add(expandingPlace.get(i)); 
            sequenceOfDuplicates.add(expandingPlace.get(i + 1));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sequenceOfDuplicates); // What was in duplicate there.

}

}
```

It adds numbers from 0 to 9 to a list, and it adds to another list what is in "duplicate" (a number followed by the same number). You can use your big list instead of my randomNumbers ArrayList.

Comment: -1: This code assumes that the random numbers are sorted, which isn't the case when you generate them at random. This code will also crash when there are no duplicates. This code will also report a whole bunch of duplicates to much. To see what I mean with these remarks, test this code on these list: `3, 1, 3` (no duplicates found!) and `1, 2, 3` (crash!) and `1, 1, 1` (four times `1` will be reported in the duplicate list!).

Comment: You're right. The random numbers were just a way that I found to fill the list with random information (Giving the fact that I don't know how his list would be).