# Java 8 streams to find the duplicate elements

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to list out duplicate elements in an integer list using Streams of JDK 8.  For example:

```java
// Duplicates are {1, 4}
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,1,3,4,4});
```

To remove duplicates we can use the [`distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) method. But what about finding the duplicated elements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Collect stream with grouping, counting and filtering operations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30515792/collect-stream-with-grouping-counting-and-filtering-operations)

Comment: If you don't want to collect the stream, this essentially boils down to "how can I look at more than one item at once in a stream"?

Comment: Set<Integer> items = new HashSet();                                                                                                           
 numbers.stream().filter(n -> i!tems.add(n)).collect(Collectors.toSet());

Answer (score 149):

You can use [`Collections.frequency`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Object-):

```
numbers.stream().filter(i -> Collections.frequency(numbers, i) >1)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: The same O(n^2) performance as in @OussamaZoghlami [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27691091/4856258), though probably simpler. Nevertheless here's an upvote. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: As mentioned, this is a n^2 solution where a trivial linear solution exists. I wouldn't accept this in CR.

Comment: It may be slower than @Dave option, but it's prettier so I'll take the performance hit.

Comment: @jwilner is your point regarding n^2 solution referring to the use of Collections.frequency in a filter?

Comment: @mancocapac yes, it's quadratic because the frequency call has to visit every element in numbers, and it's being called on every element. Thus, for each element, we visit every element -- n^2 and needlessly inefficient.

Answer (score 105):

Basic example. First-half builds the frequency-map, second-half reduces it to a filtered list. Probably not as efficient as Dave's answer, but more versatile (like if you want to detect exactly two etc.)

```
List<Integer> duplicates = IntStream.of( 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2 )
   .boxed()
   .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( Function.identity(), Collectors.counting() ) )
   .entrySet()
   .stream()
   .filter( p -> p.getValue() > 1 )
   .map( Map.Entry::getKey )
   .collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Comment: This answer is the correct one imo because it is linear and doesn't violate the "stateless predicate" rule.

Comment: @jwilner Its not really, `Collectors.counting()` is the same as the above answer. and IMHO, in a small set the above one is much simpler and cleaner

Comment: @kidnan1991 it is not the same. In above answer, each item is filtered against it's frequency, for each item again. That is really something else than making a map.

Answer (score 69):

You need a set (`allItems` below) to hold the entire array contents, but this is O(n):

```
Integer[] numbers = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4 };
Set<Integer> allItems = new HashSet<>();
Set<Integer> duplicates = Arrays.stream(numbers)
        .filter(n -> !allItems.add(n)) //Set.add() returns false if the item was already in the set.
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(duplicates); // [1, 4]
```

Comment: I think this is the most efficient solution.

Comment: `filter()` requires a stateless predicate.  Your "solution" is strikingly similar to the example of a stateful predicate given in the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness

Comment: @MattMcHenry: does that mean this solution has the potential to produce unexpected behavior, or is it just bad practice?

Comment: @IcedDante In a localized case like there where you know for sure that the stream is `sequential()`, it's *probably* safe.  In the more general case where the stream may be `parallel()`, it's pretty much guaranteed to break in weird ways.

Comment: In addition to producing unexpected behavior in some situations, this mixes paradigms as Bloch argues you shouldn't in the third edition of Effective Java. If you find yourself writing this, just use a for loop.

Comment: Although the approach is up to discussion for a production-level code, this is a pretty good coding exercise. Parallel execution can be fixed with synchronization, it won't break anything. Further more, this can be done in a one-liner - without declaring the `Set<Integer> allItems = new HashSet<>();`

Comment: Found this in the wild being used by Hibernate Validator [UniqueElements](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/fb6450dfec46d19eb1411362bff9cb2b1ab240b4/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/hv/UniqueElementsValidator.java#L64) constraint.

Answer (score 20):

An O(n) way would be as below:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4);
Set<Integer> duplicatedNumbersRemovedSet = new HashSet<>();
Set<Integer> duplicatedNumbersSet = numbers.stream().filter(n -> !duplicatedNumbersRemovedSet.add(n)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

The space complexity would go double in this approach, but that space is not a waste; in-fact, we now have the duplicated alone only as a Set as well as another Set with all the duplicates removed too.

Comment: Looks like the same solution as Dave's above - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30741906/435605

Answer (score 18):

My [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library which enhances the Java 8 streams provides a special operation [`distinct(atLeast)`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#distinct-long-) which can retain only elements appearing at least the specified number of times. So your problem can be solved like this:

```
List<Integer> repeatingNumbers = StreamEx.of(numbers).distinct(2).toList();
```

Internally it's similar to @Dave solution, it counts objects, to support other wanted quantities and it's parallel-friendly (it uses `ConcurrentHashMap` for parallelized stream, but `HashMap` for sequential). For big amounts of data you can get a speed-up using `.parallel().distinct(2)`.

Comment: The question is about Java Streams, not third-party libraries.

Answer (score 8):

You can get the duplicated like this :

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4);
Set<Integer> duplicated = numbers
  .stream()
  .filter(n -> numbers
        .stream()
        .filter(x -> x == n)
        .count() > 1)
   .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Isn't that an O(n^2) operation?

Comment: Try to use `numbers = Arrays.asList(400, 400, 500, 500);`

Comment: Is this similar to creating a 2 depth loop? for(..) { for(..) } Just curios how internally it works

Comment: Though it is a nice approach, yet having `stream` inside `stream` is costly.

Answer (score 4):

I think basic solutions to the question should be as below:

```
Supplier supplier=HashSet::new; 
HashSet has=ls.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(supplier));

List lst = (List) ls.stream().filter(e->Collections.frequency(ls,e)>1).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

well, it is not recommended to perform a filter operation, but for better understanding, i have used it, moreover, there should be some custom filtration in future versions.

Answer (score 4):

A multiset is a structure maintaining the number of occurrences for each element. Using Guava implementation:

```
Set<Integer> duplicated =
        ImmutableMultiset.copyOf(numbers).entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getCount() > 1)
                .map(Multiset.Entry::getElement)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to detect the presence of duplicates (instead of listing them, which is what the OP wanted), just convert them into both a List and Set, then compare the sizes:

```
    List<Integer> list = ...;
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(list);
    if (list.size() != set.size()) {
      // duplicates detected
    }
```

I like this approach because it has less places for mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

*the creating of an additional map or stream is time- and space-consuming…*

```
Set<Integer> duplicates = numbers.stream().collect( Collectors.collectingAndThen(
  Collectors.groupingBy( Function.identity(), Collectors.counting() ),
  map -> {
    map.values().removeIf( cnt -> cnt < 2 );
    return( map.keySet() );
  } ) );  // [1, 4]
```

*…and for the question of which is claimed to be a* [[duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57083672/java-8-streams-how-to-avoid-filtering-with-map-or-set)

```
public static int[] getDuplicatesStreamsToArray( int[] input ) {
  return( IntStream.of( input ).boxed().collect( Collectors.collectingAndThen(
      Collectors.groupingBy( Function.identity(), Collectors.counting() ),
      map -> {
        map.values().removeIf( cnt -> cnt < 2 );
        return( map.keySet() );
      } ) ).stream().mapToInt( i -> i ).toArray() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about checking of indexes?

```
        numbers.stream()
            .filter(integer -> numbers.indexOf(integer) != numbers.lastIndexOf(integer))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Should work fine, but also O(n^2) performance as some other solutions here.

Answer (score 1):

**Set.add()** is faster if you're looking for performance.

```
public class FindDuplicatedBySet {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(5, 3, 4, 1, 3, 7, 2,3,1, 9, 9, 4,1);
    Set<Integer> result = findDuplicatedBySetAdd(list);
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
  }

public static <T> Set<T> findDuplicatedBySetAdd(List<T> list) {
    Set<T> items = new HashSet<>();
    return list.stream()
            .filter(n -> !items.add(n))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is this not the best and easiest answer of them all ?
Some benchmark test shows its fastest too.  https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-find-duplicate-elements-in-a-stream/

Answer (score 1):

Using stream

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
list.stream()
     .filter(data -> !set.add(data))
     .forEach(data -> System.out.println("duplicates "+data));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have good solution how to fix problem like this - List => List with grouping by Something.a & Something.b.
There is extended definition:

```
public class Test {

    public static void test() {

        class A {
            private int a;
            private int b;
            private float c;
            private float d;

            public A(int a, int b, float c, float d) {
                this.a = a;
                this.b = b;
                this.c = c;
                this.d = d;
            }
        }


        List<A> list1 = new ArrayList<A>();

        list1.addAll(Arrays.asList(new A(1, 2, 3, 4),
                new A(2, 3, 4, 5),
                new A(1, 2, 3, 4),
                new A(2, 3, 4, 5),
                new A(1, 2, 3, 4)));

        Map<Integer, A> map = list1.stream()
                .collect(HashMap::new, (m, v) -> m.put(
                        Objects.hash(v.a, v.b, v.c, v.d), v),
                        HashMap::putAll);

        list1.clear();
        list1.addAll(map.values());

        System.out.println(list1);
    }

}
```

class A, list1 it's just incoming data - magic is in the Objects.hash(...) :)

Comment: Warning: If `Objects.hash` produces the same value for `(v.a_1, v.b_1, v.c_1, v.d_1)` and `(v.a_2, v.b_2, v.c_2, v.d_2)`, then they are going to be considered equal and be removed as duplicates, without actually checking that the a's, b's, c's, and d's are the same.  This may be an acceptable risk, or you may want to use a function other than `Objects.hash` which is guaranteed to produce a unique result across your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use the java 8 idioms (steams)? Perphaps a simple solution would be to move the complexity to a map alike data structure that holds numbers as key (without repeating) and the times it ocurrs as a value. You could them iterate that map an only do something with those numbers that are ocurrs > 1.

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class RemoveDuplicates
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,1,3,4,4});
   Map<Integer,Integer> countByNumber = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
   for(Integer n:numbers)
   {
     Integer count = countByNumber.get(n);
     if (count != null) {
       countByNumber.put(n,count + 1);
     } else {
       countByNumber.put(n,1);
     }
   }
   System.out.println(countByNumber);
   Iterator it = countByNumber.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
public class Anagramm {

public static boolean isAnagramLetters(String word, String anagramm) {
    if (anagramm.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    Map<Character, Integer> mapExistString = CharCountMap(word);
    Map<Character, Integer> mapCheckString = CharCountMap(anagramm);
    return enoughLetters(mapExistString, mapCheckString);
}

private static Map<Character, Integer> CharCountMap(String chars) {
    HashMap<Character, Integer> charCountMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (char c : chars.toCharArray()) {
        if (charCountMap.containsKey(c)) {
            charCountMap.put(c, charCountMap.get(c) + 1);
        } else {
            charCountMap.put(c, 1);
        }
    }
    return charCountMap;
}

static boolean enoughLetters(Map<Character, Integer> mapExistString, Map<Character,Integer> mapCheckString) {
    for( Entry<Character, Integer> e : mapCheckString.entrySet() ) {
        Character letter = e.getKey();
        Integer available = mapExistString.get(letter);
        if (available == null || e.getValue() > available) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**How to find Non-Repeated Numbers from the array using java8**

Integer[] intArr = {1,1,3,2,2,5,4,4,7,6,6,9,8,8,10,13};

Set<Integer> result = Arrays.asList(intArr).stream().
filter(x -> Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(intArr), x) == 1).
        collect(Collectors.toSet());

 System.out.println(result); //output : [3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 13] **Non-duplicate** values


**How to find repeated Numbers from array using java8**

Set<Integer> set = new HashSet();

Set<Integer> result = Arrays.asList(intArr).stream().filter(x -> !set.add(x)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    
System.out.println(result); // output : [1, 2, 4, 6, 8]  it returns **Duplicates values.**
```

Comment: part 1 is not an answer to the question, part 2 is (basically) a copy of an earlier answer - what news am I missing? btw: please format your answer properly (in code, indentation matters and not-in-code should be .. not formatted as such ;)

Answer (score 0):

The [JEP 461: Stream Gatherers](https://openjdk.org/jeps/461) Java 22 preview language feature adds support for gatherer operations, which could be used to filter the stream for duplicates:

```java
void main() {
    List<Integer> numbers = List.of(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1);
    List<Integer> duplicates = numbers.stream().gather(duplicates()).toList();
    System.out.println(duplicates); // [1, 4]
}

static <T> Gatherer<T, ?, T> duplicates() {
    Gatherer.Integrator.Greedy<Map<T, Integer>, T, T> integrator =
            (state, element, downstream) -> {
                Integer occurrences =
                        state.compute(element, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
                if (occurrences == 2) {
                    return downstream.push(element);
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            };
    return Gatherer.ofSequential(
            HashMap::new,
            Gatherer.Integrator.ofGreedy(integrator)
    );
}
```

The custom gatherer keeps track of the number of occurrences of each value, and pushes an element downstream whenever the second instance of the value is encountered.  This way, each distinct element is passed downstream once it is identified as a duplicate, and no other times.

Granted, this is a fair amount of code in isolation, but it can be reused as an intermediate operation in any stream that needs to operate only on duplicates.

## Javadocs

[`Gatherer`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html):

> An intermediate operation that transforms a stream of input elements into a stream of output elements, optionally applying a final action when the end of the upstream is reached. […]
>
> […]
>
> There are many examples of gathering operations, including but not limited to: grouping elements into batches (windowing functions); de-duplicating consecutively similar elements; incremental accumulation functions (prefix scan); incremental reordering functions, etc. The class [`Gatherers`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html) provides implementations of common gathering operations.
>
> **API Note:**
>
> A `Gatherer` is specified by four functions that work together to process input elements, optionally using intermediate state, and optionally perform a final action at the end of input. They are:
>
> - creating a new, potentially mutable, state ([`initializer()`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#initializer()))
> - integrating a new input element ([`integrator()`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#integrator()))
> - combining two states into one ([`combiner()`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#combiner()))
> - performing an optional final action ([`finisher()`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#finisher()))

[`Stream.gather(Gatherer<? super T,?,R> gatherer)`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given gatherer to the elements of this stream.

[`Gatherer.ofSequential(initializer, integrator)`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#ofSequential(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Gatherer.Integrator))

> Returns a new, sequential, `Gatherer` described by the given `initializer` and `integrator`.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the OP asked for streams, but perhaps streams is the wrong approach for the job at hand.

I love streams and use it all the time, but in this case I would suggest a simple O(n) operation

```
private Set<Integer> findDuplicates(List<Integer> values) {
    final List<Integer> mutableList = new ArrayList<>(values);
    final Set<Integer> removedValues = new HashSet<>();

    mutableList.removeIf(v -> {
        boolean alreadyRemoved = removedValues.contains(v);
        removedValues.add(v);
        return !alreadyRemoved;
    });
    return new HashSet<>(mutableList);
}
```

`removeIf` internally performs a loop and invokes the given `Predicate` parameter for each element. If returns true then the element gets removed. It returns false if the predicate is invoked again for the same element, preventing it from being deleted.
At the end, only the duplicates remain.

Unit test

```
@DataProvider
private Object[][] testDuplicatesProvider() {
    return new Object[][] {{
            ImmutableList.of(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4),
            ImmutableSet.of(1, 4)
        }, {
            ImmutableList.of(1, 2, 2, 5, 2, 6, 7, 6),
            ImmutableSet.of(2, 6)
        }, {
            ImmutableList.of(1, 2, 3),
            ImmutableSet.of()
        }, {
            ImmutableList.of(),
            ImmutableSet.of()
        }
    };
}

@Test(dataProvider = "testDuplicatesProvider")
public void testDuplicates(@Nonnull List<Integer> testData,
                           @Nonnull Set<Integer> expectedResult) {
    Assert.assertEquals(findDuplicates(testData), expectedResult);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using distinct on stream would filter duplicates, you can either collect as set or List.

```
 numbers.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Comment: The question is how to find the duplicates, not remove them.