# Collect stream with grouping, counting and filtering operations

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to collect stream throwing away rarely used items like in this example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsInAnyOrder;
import org.junit.Test;

@Test
public void shouldFilterCommonlyUsedWords() {
    // given
    List<String> allWords = Arrays.asList(
       "call", "feel", "call", "very", "call", "very", "feel", "very", "any");

    // when
    Set<String> commonlyUsed = allWords.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()))
            .entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() > 2)
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(toSet());

    // then
    assertThat(commonlyUsed, containsInAnyOrder("call", "very"));
}
```

I have a feeling that it is possible to do it much simpler - am I right?

Comment: No, that looks like about the simplest way to do it.

Comment: @LouisWasserman But it is so ugly construction to with intermediate `Map` in it.

Comment: So? There is going to have to be something like a Map in the implementation to do the counting.  There's no way around that.

Comment: You can replace `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(…))` by a simple `Arrays.asList(…)`. There is only one way to avoid a map which is calculating the frequency again for each item but that’s `O(n²)` CPU complexity, so I guess you better live with the intermediate map…

Comment: You can also use `.collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(i ->i, counting()),
                        m -> m.entrySet()....toSet()));` although you don't gain much in readability.

Comment: What this question attempts to do is equivalent to the SQL statement `SELECT word FROM allWords GROUP BY word HAVING count(*) > 2`.  The `groupingBy` `Collector` does the job of `GROUP BY`, but there is no `HAVING` clause equivalent.  It would be good for Java to add that functionality, e.g. something like `groupingBy(Function<? super T,? extends K> classifier, Collector<? super T,A,D> downstream, Predicate<? super D> having)`.

Comment: @rgettman Yes, I thought about that query and even wanted to add it to the question.

Comment: @rgettman: I don’t see the advantage of such a method. It’s only hiding the fact that it has to collect the entire map first, before filtering just like in my answer…

Comment: @Holger Then why have a `HAVING` clause in SQL?  It's just hiding the fact that the group by and aggregate operations happen before the aggregate values are filtered.  Once could write `SELECT word FROM (SELECT word, count(*) c FROM allWords GROUP BY word) WHERE c > 2;`.  Having `HAVING` allows more concise code.  One can certainly use your solution; it will work.  I just pointed out that it would be good for Java to have the `HAVING` option that would simplify the code.

Comment: @rgettman: SQL is an entirely different thing. It’s there to hide what’s really going on. Of course, you could nest two SQL statements and on some DBs that will be even faster, but on most DBs it is significantly slower. So what’s the conclusion? I’m glad that Java *is not* SQL. And I doubt that an equivalent of a `HAVING` clause was so often needed that it required special API support. If you want to perform database operations, consider using a database…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A while ago I [wrote](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/commit/c1904fe873f92ba357c7f0897371f15828e02afc) an experimental `distinct(atLeast)` method for my library:

```
public StreamEx<T> distinct(long atLeast) {
    if (atLeast <= 1)
        return distinct();
    AtomicLong nullCount = new AtomicLong();
    ConcurrentHashMap<T, Long> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return filter(t -> {
        if (t == null) {
            return nullCount.incrementAndGet() == atLeast;
        }
        return map.merge(t, 1L, (u, v) -> (u + v)) == atLeast;
    });
}
```

So the idea was to use it like this:

```
Set<String> commonlyUsed = StreamEx.of(allWords).distinct(3).toSet();
```

This performs a stateful filtration, which looks a little bit ugly. I doubted whether such feature is useful thus I did not merge it into the master branch. Nevertheless it does the job in single stream pass. Probably I should revive it. Meanwhile you can copy this code into the static method and use it like this:

```
Set<String> commonlyUsed = distinct(allWords.stream(), 3).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

**Update (2015/05/31)**: I added the [`distinct(atLeast)`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#distinct-long-) method to the StreamEx 0.3.1. It's implemented using [custom spliterator](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/blob/master/src/main/java/one/util/streamex/DistinctSpliterator.java). Benchmarks showed that this implementation is significantly faster for sequential streams than stateful filtering described above and in many cases it's also faster than other solutions proposed in this topic. Also it works nicely if `null` is encountered in the stream (the `groupingBy` collector doesn't support `null` as class, thus `groupingBy`-based solutions will fail if `null` is encountered).

Comment: @Holger, thanks, [will use](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/commit/8cc7f632c87affdd0701847df41a778abc79aef2) `Long::sum`. I want to test also [custom spliterator](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/blob/8cc7f632c87affdd0701847df41a778abc79aef2/src/main/java/javax/util/streamex/DistinctSpliterator.java) version: it's somewhat longer implementation, but adds a possibility to use simple `HashMap` for sequential streams (if `trySplit` was not called), thus may work faster.

Comment: Did you profile your solution? I would not make a guess about which costs more, the uncontended synchronization of `ConcurrentHashMap.merge` or the *unbox,unbox,sum,box* operation made for almost each element. Only a profiler may tell…

Comment: Sure I will benchmark both versions on different data sizes and different patterns (like many repeats, few repeats, no repeats, presorted and shuffled input, no nulls, many nulls) and compare with intermediate map solution (either with removeIf or with creating second stream), both in parallel and sequential. I think, it's reasonable to add it to the library only if it's at least as fast as using the intermediate map. Of course if simpler version performs well I will use it.

Comment: Well, benchmarking afterwards is not the same as profiling beforehand. Of course, it’s a good thing that you verify the result. I just consider the possibility that a customized map storing `long` values rather than `Long` instances might have a much bigger performance impact but I wouldn’t waste time implementing such a solution before a profiler tells me that there really *could* be a benefit. Well a `Spliterator` is easier to implement and you already did that, so you may benchmark now. But I recommend profiling before deciding, which attempt for further improvement to make.

Comment: @Holger: seems that spliterator is better: the benchmark and results are [here](https://gist.github.com/amaembo/669ddaf83fadd2920e83). In sequential tests spliterator (distinct2) is always better than filter (distinct) and in most cases better than other solutions proposed here (double-stream and remove-if). In parallel tests distinct and distinct2 show similar performance and faster than other solutions roughly in a half of cases. Thus I'd stay with spliterator solution. Customized primitive map may be even faster, but it's too much for my library (especially considering the concurrent case).

Comment: The github link to the source code result in HTTP 404.

Answer (score 11):

There is no way around creating a `Map`, unless you want accept a very high CPU complexity.

However, you can remove the *second* `collect` operation:

```
Map<String,Long> map = allWords.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), HashMap::new, counting()));
map.values().removeIf(l -> l<=2);
Set<String> commonlyUsed=map.keySet();
```

Note that in Java 8, `HashSet` still wraps a `HashMap`, so using the `keySet()` of a `HashMap`, when you want a `Set` in the first place, doesn’t waste space given the current implementation.

Of course, you can hide the post-processing in a `Collector` if that feels more “streamy”:

```
Set<String> commonlyUsed = allWords.stream()
    .collect(collectingAndThen(
        groupingBy(Function.identity(), HashMap::new, counting()),
        map-> { map.values().removeIf(l -> l<=2); return map.keySet(); }));
```

Comment: Strictly speaking you may still waste space for allocated `Long` objects (if any of your counts exceed `127`).

Comment: Also if you have quite many rare items which are filtered out with `removeIf`, you may end up with very big hash table which will not be shrinked automatically.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: both could be solved with a customized `Map` implementation, however, the question is how the `commonlyUsed` `Set` is being used afterwards, maybe this is no issue at all.

Comment: @Holger `groupingBy(Function.identity(), HashMap::new, counting())` is absolutely identical to `groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting())` (I know that you know but maybe others don't).

Comment: From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-): “*There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Map returned.*”. The **current implementation** returns a `HashMap` but you *must not* rely on it. So if you need a mutable map like in my solution you should specify a supplier like `HashMap::new`.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer Holger's solution (+1), but, instead of removing elements from the groupingBy map, I would *filter* its entrySet and *map* the result to a Set in the finalizer (it feels even more *streamy* to me)

```
    Set<String> commonlyUsed = allWords.stream().collect(
            collectingAndThen(
                groupingBy(identity(), counting()), 
                (map) -> map.entrySet().stream().
                            filter(e -> e.getValue() > 2).
                            map(e -> e.getKey()).
                            collect(Collectors.toSet())));
```