# How can I get two keys with duplicate values and print it?

Tags: java

I have method `getKeyFromValue` for **LinkedHashMap** and I want to get key from the value of this map. How can I get two keys with duplicate values and print it like

```
System.out.print( getKeyFromValue(hashmap, value1), getKeyFromValue(hashmap, value2) )

key1 = 1, key2 = 2
value1 = value2 = 1

private static Object getKeyFromValue(Map hm, Object value) {
        for (Object o : hm.keySet()) {
            if (hm.get(o).equals(value)) {
                return o;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You can go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55309116/how-to-print-keys-with-duplicate-values-in-a-hashmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a method `getKeysFromValue()` and have it return an `array` or a `List` of the keys.

```
key1 = 1, key2 = 2
value1 = value2 = 1
```

/* put the key - values into the map */

```
private static List<Object> getKeysFromValue(Map hm, Object value) {
    List<Object> rtn = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object o : hm.keySet()) {
        if (hm.get(o).equals(value)) {
            rtn.add(o);
        }
    }
    return rtn;
}
```