# Java 8 Streams how to avoid filtering with map or set?

Tags: java, java-stream

I keep running into solutions where I want/think i need to save state via either a Map or a Set.
e.g.   create a method that returns duplicates found in the input

```
// non streams solution
public int[] getDuplicates(int[] input){
  Set<Integer> allSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
  Set<Integer> duplicates = new HashSet<Integer>();

  int[] dups = new int[input.length];
  int j = 0;
  for (Integer i : input) {
    if (!allSet.add(i)) {
      if(duplicates.add(i)) {
        dups[j++] = i;
      }
    }
  }
  return Arrays.copyOfRange(dups, 0, j);
}
```

My Java 8 Streams solution, unfortunately I am using a HashSet for filtering. I understand this is not "proper" as it depends on state.
Is no state a suggestion or a hard-fast rule? Is it only an issue when running a parallel stream? Can someone suggest a way not to use HashSet here?

```
public static int[] getDuplicatesStreamsToArray(int[] input) {
  Set<Integer> allSet = new HashSet<>();
  int[] dups = Arrays.stream(input)
      .sequential()                   // prevents parallel processing
      .unordered()                    // speed up distinct operation
      .boxed()                        // int to Integer
      .filter(n -> !allSet.add(n))    // passes dups, but uses STATE
      .distinct()                     // uses internal Set of dups
      .mapToInt(i -> i)               // Integer back to int
      .toArray();
  return dups;
}
```

Comment: see: [_…and for the question of which is claimed to be a_ \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677256/java-8-streams-to-find-the-duplicate-elements/57106549#57106549)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

Basically, creates a frequency count of type `Map<Integer,Long>` and returns those `keys` where the `value` is greater than 1.

```java
    public static int[] getDuplicatesStreamsToArray(int[] input) {

      int[] dups = Arrays.stream(input).boxed().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                  Collectors.counting())).entrySet().stream().filter(
                        e -> e.getValue() > 1).mapToInt(
                              e -> e.getKey()).toArray();
      return dups;
   }
```

I misunderstood what you were trying to do earlier.

Comment: This does not return the duplicates.

Comment: I modified my answer.

Comment: This works for me. Followup question if I may, would @WJS use this solution over the non-streams solution above? What is the Big O of this solution?