# Problem finding duplicate numbers in array, is my technique bad?

Tags: java, duplicates

I used a HashMap to store the occurrences of each element, and then iterated over the hash map to get duplicated element, but something doesn't feel right about this solution.

Problem statement in Firecode.io:

> Write a method duplicate to find the repeated or duplicate elements in an array. This method should return a list of repeated integers in a string with the elements sorted in ascending order (as illustrated below).
>
> `duplicate({1,3,4,2,1})` --> `"[1]"`
>
> `duplicate({1,3,4,2,1,2,4})` --> `"[1, 2, 4]"`
>
> Note: You may use toString() method to return the standard string representation of most data structures, and Arrays.sort() to sort your result.*

Here is my code:

```
 public String duplicate(int[] numbers) {
      HashMap < Integer, Integer > hs = new HashMap < Integer, Integer > ();
      for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
           if (hs.get(numbers[i]) == null) {
                hs.put(numbers[i], 1);
           } else hs.put(numbers[i], (Integer) hs.get(numbers[i]) + 1);
      }

      int size = 0;
      for (int i: hs.keySet()) {
           if (hs.get(i) > 1) {
                size++;
           }
      }
      int j = 0;
      int[] a = new int[size];
      for (int i: hs.keySet()) {
           if (hs.get(i) > 1) {
                a[j++] = i;
           }
      }

      Arrays.sort(a);
      return Arrays.toString(a);
 }
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to duplicate the text?

Comment: what is exactly what you don't like ?

Comment: "something doesn't feel right" is a tiny bit vague as a problem description. Unrelated: take the habit to always be consistent on the use of braces for `if-else` blocks

Comment: I think this question is in the wrong overflow.  It would be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31341963/1121249

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the way I would do it: (comments for educational purposes, would probably not have them in production code.)

```
public String duplicate(int[] numbers) {

  // holds the items we've encountered more than once.
  // TreeSet<> keeps things in sorted order for us.
  final SortedSet<Integer> duplicates = new TreeSet<>();

  // keeps track of items we've encountered.
  final Set<Integer> encountered = new HashSet<>(); 

  // iterate over every number
  for (final int number : numbers) {
    // Add the item to encountered. Set.add() will return true if 
    // the element is new to the set.
    if (!encountered.add(number)) {
       // Since the element wasn't new, ensure this item exists in the duplicates collection.
       duplicates.add(number);
    }
  }

  return duplicates.toString();
}
```

Comment: I'd use `SortedSet<Integer> duplicates = new TreeSet<>()` to signify why we have `TreeSet`.

Comment: I thought about that @KarolDowbecki, but I decided that since we didn't need any of the methods in `SortedSet`, it was unnecessary.  To that end, I could have made them all `Collection`, I guess.  *shrug* its subjective.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki, I decided to go with your suggestion, and edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have to tell how many times an element is duplicated you only need a `Set` to remember which elements are unique and which not. If you know the element values (e.g. numbers between 1 and 10) you could further simplify `Set` to `boolean[]` or a bit vector:

```
int[] numbers = {1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4};
Set<Integer> unique = new HashSet<>();
Set<Integer> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
for (int n : numbers) {
    if (!unique.add(n)) {
        duplicates.add(n);
    }
}
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(duplicates);
result.sort(Integer::compareTo);
System.out.println(result); // [1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Looks very similar to the answer I almost gave, until I realized you could use `TreeSet<>` for the `duplicates` value, and skip the whole sorting phase.

Comment: `TreeSet` would trade cost of insertion for cost of sorting `List` at the end. There ain't no such thing as a free lunch.

Comment: True, but it reduces the cognitive load of trying to understand the method.  It also removes the need to copy values out of the `duplicates` into the `result` list.  The overhead of maintaining a Tree might outway the runtime cost, but it might not.  FWIW, you can use `Collections.sort(result)` to avoid the `Integer::compareTo`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 or beyond you can try:

```
public String duplicate(int[] numbers) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> hs = new HashMap<>();
    for ( int i : numbers ) {
        hs.merge( i, 1, Integer::sum);
    }
    return '[' + 
             hs.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .filter( e -> e.getValue() > 1 )
               .map(Entry::getKey)
               .sorted()
               .map(i -> i.toString())
               .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) +
           ']';
}
```

Comment: too streamy maybe