# Get all objects from a list with a duplicate property using Java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following issue:

Goal: I want literally all of instances of "City" that have duplicates based on "name".

Restraints: I need to use streams.

Errors: There are no errors.

Description:

I have a list of instances of the class "City".
The goal is to have a list with literaly all of the duplicates found based on "name", and not just one, using stream.

I have tried to research answers to my issue, but all answers found, only explain how add the element that is being repeated once, and not twice or three times if situation calls for it.

Research material that I found:

- [Java 8 streams to find the duplicate elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677256/java-8-streams-to-find-the-duplicate-elements) (Stack Overflow)
- [Java 8 – Find duplicate elements in a Stream](https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-find-duplicate-elements-in-a-stream/) (mkyong.com)

Goal again: With the list displayed beneath, a new list that would be created to take in the duplicates, would have inside the instace of "Lisboa" 3x, the instace of "Braga" 3x and the instace of "Guarda" 2x, this is because these are the repeated elements based on the name.

The list would contain instances of type "City", that have the names repeated.

Main:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<City> portugalCities = List.of(
                new City("Lisboa", "Estremadura", 2275591),
                new City("Lisboa", "Estremadura", 2275591),
                new City("Faro", "Algarve", 67650),
                new City("Braga", "Minho", 193324),
                new City("Braga", "Esposende", 193324),
                new City("Braga", "Fafe", 193324),
                new City("Alentejo", "Ribatejo", 704533),
                new City("Viseu", "Beira Alta", 99561),
                new City("Lisboa", "Alenquer", 2275591),
                new City("Guarda", "Almeida", 143019),
                new City("Guarda", "Aguiar da Beira", 143019)
        );
    }
}
```

City:

```java
public class City {
    private String name;
    private String province;
    private int population;
    // ----- Properties

    public City(String name, String province, int population) {
        this.name = name;
        this.province = province;
        this.population = population;
    }
    // ----- Constructor

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getProvince() {
        return province;
    }

    public void setProvince(String district) {
        this.province = district;
    }

    public int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    public void setPopulation(int population) {
        this.population = population;
    }
    // ----- Getter & Setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("|name: %s; district: %s; population: %s|", name, province, population);
    }
    // ----- toString

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        City city = (City) o;
        return population == city.population && Objects.equals(name, city.name) && Objects.equals(province, city.province);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, province, population);
    }

    // ----- Equals & hashCode
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First collect names and count them, then use that to filter out non-dupes:

```
Map<String, Long> freq = portugalCities.stream()
  .map(City::getName)
  .collect(groupingBy(n -> n, counting()));

List<City> dupes = portugalCities.stream()
  .filter(c -> freq.get(c.getName()) > 1)
  .collect(toList());
```

Then print them as you like:

```
dupes.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply.
As I see yours and other responses, I can see where I failed to explain.
My goal is to have the repeated instances, by the name.

So, not a list with only the names being repeated, but a list with all of the instances that have the name being repeated.

Apologies for the misinformation.

Comment: That is exacly it, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Ideally a stream will process its elements one at a time without the need to store intermediate results. In this case however we need to store the cities grouped by name, because we cannot know which are duplicates unless we have processed all elements. So, given the definition of class `City` and the dataset of the question, I propose the following, two-step process:

```java
Map<String, List<City>> citiesByName =
  portugalCities.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(City::getName));
List<City> result =
  citiesByName.values().stream()
    .filter(list -> list.size() > 1)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .toList();
```

Can be done in a fancier single chain, but still, there is an intermediate result, the `citiesByName`.

The result contains *all duplicates* (as I understand was the object of the question), not just a count.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use a custom collector for that, not unlike https://mdn.io/Array.reduce:

this example produces the output:

```
{Alentejo=1, Braga=3, Faro=1, Guarda=2, Lisboa=3, Viseu=1}
```

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.stream.Collector;


public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<City> portugalCities = List.of(
                new City("Lisboa", "Estremadura", 2275591),
                new City("Lisboa", "Estremadura", 2275591),
                new City("Faro", "Algarve", 67650),
                new City("Braga", "Minho", 193324),
                new City("Braga", "Esposende", 193324),
                new City("Braga", "Fafe", 193324),
                new City("Alentejo", "Ribatejo", 704533),
                new City("Viseu", "Beira Alta", 99561),
                new City("Lisboa", "Alenquer", 2275591),
                new City("Guarda", "Almeida", 143019),
                new City("Guarda", "Aguiar da Beira", 143019)
        );

        Map<String, Integer> counts = portugalCities.stream()
                .collect(Collector.<City, Map<String, Integer>>of(
                        // this means our collector starts by creating a tree map
                        // using the default constructor,
                        // which we passed here
                        TreeMap::new,
                        //
                        // then, process each element collecting to a map.
                        // basically:
                        // [{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }]
                        //  .reduce((acc /* accumulator*/, next) => {
                        //    acc[next.name] = (acc[next.name] || 0) + 1;
                        //    return acc; }, {} /* initial value of acc */)
                        (map, next) -> map.put(next.getName(),
                                map.computeIfAbsent(next.getName(), k -> 0) + 1),
                        // this is not needed, as you only have 1 map
                        // if given, it would be how to combine 2 maps (a, and b)
                        (a, b) -> {
                            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                        }
                ));

        System.out.println(counts);
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Accessors(chain = true)
    @Data
    static class City {
        private String name;
        private String province;
        private int population;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply.
I am pasting the same reply as it applies to your asnwer as well.

As I see yours and other responses, I can see where I failed to explain. My goal is to have the repeated instances, by the name. So, not a list with only the names being repeated, but a list with all of the instances that have the name being repeated. Apologies for the misinformation.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify whether the results needed to be in any particular order, but in case you need them to be in the same order as the source list, the following approach could be used:

```java
Set<String> duplicateCityNames = portugalCities.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(City::getName))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());

List<City> duplicateCities = portugalCities.stream()
        .filter(c -> duplicateCityNames.contains(c.getName()))
        .toList();
```

This first collects a `Set<String>` of the names of all duplicate cities.  It then filters through the original list, keeping only cities with names in the duplicate list.