# Collect duplicate objects from a list of objects based on property in Java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

```
class Computer{
    int id;
    String osName;

    //getter and setter of id and osName
    //this class does not contain hashcode and equals methods
}
```

I have a list of Computer objects

```
Computer c1 = new Computer(1, "Window10");
Computer c2 = new Computer(2, "Window11");
Computer c3 = new Computer(3, "Linux");
Computer c4 = new Computer(4, "Window10");
Computer c5 = new Computer(5, "Window10");
```

I need all duplicate objects list (by comparing osName) using java stream API.

```
Computer(1, "Window10")
Computer(4, "Window10")
Computer(5, "Window10")
```

Please suggest the best way to do that.

Comment: Similar to this issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677256/java-8-streams-to-find-the-duplicate-elements

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Collectors.groupingBy` to get create a `Map` of OS names to a list of computers, then filter to get only the lists with multiple elements (i.e. containing duplicates).

```java
List<Computer> duplicated = computers.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Computer::getOsName))
        .entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()).toList();
```