# How to find the nth Index in a arrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

how to find the nth index in a arraylist
ex: i hv a `List<Character> charList = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList('s', 'h','a','r','a','n'))`

```
charList.indexOf('a');
```

always gives the *first* index of the `a`.
How do I get the nth?

Comment: use the `lastIndexOf('a')` ..

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why would you store chars in a `List` instead of a `String` ? Why do you need to access the nth index of a char ?

Comment: thank you for letting me know XY Problem, sounds funny. yeah off course i have not given the context sorry for that, the question is to find the nth index of any element, in my case it happens to be the Character.. how to find the nth index of given String in case of List<String> stringList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implement of indexOf() in ArrayList:

```
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                if (elementData[i]==null)
                    return i;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                    return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

So you can try list this:

```
    public int indexNth(List charList, int n, Object _enum) {
        int index = 0;
        int findTimes = 0;
        if (n == 0)
            return -1;
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(charList))
            return -1;
        for (Object o : charList) {
            if (o.equals(_enum))
                findTimes++;
            if (findTimes >= n)
                return index;
            index++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a method for it, something like this:

```
public static <T> int indexOfNth(List<T> list, T find, int nthOccurrence) {
    if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) return -1;
    int hitCount = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
        if (list.get(index).equals(find)) {
            hitCount++;
        }
        if (hitCount == nthOccurrence) return index;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Java 8 Streams-based approach:

```
    List<Character> charList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList('s', 'h','a','r','a','n'));

    int[] allIndexes = IntStream.range(0, charList.size())
                                .filter(i -> charList.get(i).equals('a'))
                                .toArray();

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allIndexes));
```

This searches the input array `charList` for all elements that are equal to the desired element `'a'` and returns an array containing the indexes of matching elements. The Nth occurrence is at `allIndexes[N]` if N is less than `allIndexes.length`, else there is no Nth occurrence. (This assumes that N is zero-based, like array and List indexes are in Java.)

In this case the result is

```
    [2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `indexOf('a')` returns the index of the first 'a' element in the List.

In order to find the index of some nth 'a', you need to iterate through the list:

```
int count = 0;
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < charList.size(); i++) {
    if charList[i].equals('a') {
        count++;
    }
    if (count == 2) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

I assumed you are looking for the second 'a'.

Comment: maybe he wants to get the index of the second a. now you would say use lastindexof. but what if there are 3 a? how do you get the 2nd most efficient?

Comment: There are countless reasons why one would want to find the position of `x` in an array.  Because of the fact that Java's `.contains(Object o)` and `.indexOf(Object o)` both make use of `Object`'s `.equals(Object o)` (as they should), one can very easily find a user defined object within an array based on certain properties of that object.  I can't tell you the number of times that I have made use of this very functionality.  It is by no means useless....  This is especially true in the case of multidimensional arrays and parallel arrays.

Comment: Sorry all, I edited the answer. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet will return the position of a desired character from arraylist.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;


class Test4
{

    public static int find(ArrayList<Character> obj,int index,char value)
    {

        int counter=0;
        for(int i=0;i<obj.size();i++)
        {

            if(obj.get(i)==value)
            {
                counter++;
                if(counter==index)
                {
                    return i+1;
                }
            }
        }
            return -1;

    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {

       ArrayList<Character> charList = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList('s', 'h','a','r','a','n'));


  // The following parameters to method find are as find the position of second character 'a' in the ArrayList

       System.out.println(find(charList,2,'a'));

    }

}
```

If the character does not exist it will return -1.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int indexOf(List<Object> tokens, int n, Object obj) {
        int times = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
            if (tokens.get(i) == obj && n == ++times) {
                return ++i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```